# What is the difference between SDF Annotation and SDF back annotation?

Tags: verilog

what is the difference between SDF annotation and SDF back annotation?
I am seeing both of these in gatelevel simulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People use these terms interchangeably. However the IEEE 1800-2017 LRM uses the term SDF annotation when talking about the data in the SDF file, which is actually defined in another standard, 1497-2001. The terms **back**-annotation and **forward**-annotation refer to a process for using that data.

> SDF contains constructs for the description of computed timing data
> for back-annotation and the specification of timing constraints for
> forward-annotation. There is no restriction on using both sets of
> constructs in the same file. Indeed, some design synthesis tools (such
> as floorplanners) may need access to computed timing data as well as
> the timing constraints intended to be meet.

Answer (score 0):

Backward Annotation of SDF is used in the design analysis if u perform simulation of post place and route model.
Forward Annotation of SDF is done by the Analysis tool and given to synthesis tool and is tool specific. u can refer @http://ce.sharif.edu/courses/85-86/2/ce483/resources/root/sdf_3.0.pdf